# How to add conditional item-right or item-left to an ion-avatar?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am having problems getting conditional attribute item-left and item-right to work on an element in an ion-item. It seems that the whole html output actually changes if I use item-left and item-right.

What I am trying to achieve is a simple chat application that shows the ion-avatar either on the left or right side in an ion-list. Below is an example of what I am trying to achieve. The method isMe() returns true or false depending on whether the current message shown is from me or not.

```
  <ion-list no-lines>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let msg of messages" text-wrap>
      <ion-avatar [attr.item-left]="isMe(msg.userid) ? '' : null" [attr.item-right]="isMe(msg.userid) ? null : ''">
        <img [src]="getAvatar(msg.avatar)">
      </ion-avatar>
      <div class="chatbubble {{isMe(msg.userid) ? '' : 'other'}}" item-content>
          {{msg.message}}
      </div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

If I hardcode a list with two ion-items each with item-left and item-right on their respective ion-avatars it does show up correctly, but for some reason wrapping this in an ngFor has not been working well. As I mentioned, studying the html output the item-right actually seems to sort the html output to achieve the difference between item-left or right so it would seem these attributes are compile time effects?

Update! I did figure out one way of solving this using *ngIf, although rather ugly as I can't use the *ngIf on the ion-item since the *ngFor is on that already as the repeated element. So I had ot use *ngIf's on every tag under that. Below is code that works, although would love to have tips on better doing this. Wrapping the tags in two divs does not work as the item-left and item-right needs to be on the ion-avatar in order for ionic2 to create the correct html output for these two cases. Anyway, if anyone needs it, the code below works fine in this case (although ugly).

```
  <ion-list no-lines>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let msg of messages" text-wrap>
      <ion-avatar item-left *ngIf="isMe(msg.userid)">
        <img [src]="getAvatar(msg.avatar)">
      </ion-avatar>        
      <div class="chatbubble" item-content *ngIf="isMe(msg.userid)">
          {{msg.message}}
      </div>
      <ion-avatar item-right *ngIf="!isMe(msg.userid)">
        <img [src]="getAvatar(msg.avatar)">
      </ion-avatar>        
      <div class="chatbubble other" item-content *ngIf="!isMe(msg.userid)">
          {{msg.message}}
      </div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Comment: As an additional comment I have noticed that the output html actually wraps the ion-avatar inside an ion-label, so that is possibly the problem here as its trying to float the avatar right inside the label which surely does not work. I find it odd however that the html output is so different to the actual markup in my template.

Answer (score 0):

1) you should avoid logic in the view

2) it is better to create a flag method in the controller, for example

```
  private isMe : boolean = false;
```

and dynamically check it for a given list of messages

3)  displaying it using a css class in the view

```
  <div [class.my-custom-class-with-item-left]="isMe">
```

that gives you a better separation of the concerns :)

Comment: Well I did try the whole expression in the code as well. It does not work still. The "item-right" attribute (note its not a class) is in fact there on the output html but the ion-avatar is not actually to the right in the output/display. But thanks for the tip on number 3 for a conditional class which looks cleaner.